# Command output in rails console: Explanation of unwanted output?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working with the rails console, and some models.  I am running things like:

```
Model.find(:all).each do |x| p x.name end
```

which is nice, this lets me see all the values of a specific column, but after it prints those lines, it prints out the whole model.

Why does it do this?  How can I stop it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Console always prints the return value of the command. And the return value for `.each` is the initial array.

So you either return the value you need:

```
Model.find(:all).map{ |x| x.name }
```

Or prevent output, returning something like nil:

```
Model.find(:all).each{ |x| p x.name }; nil
```